# Compare routes between Linux hosts

Tags: linux, route, iproute

I have groups of hosts which require specific routes per group.

Every now and again routes are modified, and I would like to write a script which can check for differences between hosts on the same group.

I've tried comparing the outputs of the `ip r` command, but there are small differences between each hosts (such as the interface names and metric) which cause false positives.

For example, suppose I have the following hosts, routes and VLAN's (all fabricated for this example):

```
Host 1:
10.0.0.30 via 192.168.0.1 VLAN 1 
100.50.10.10 via 10.0.0.1 VLAN 2
```

And host 2 has only the following:

```
Host 2:
10.0.0.30 via 192.168.0.1 VLAN 1
```

I would like the script to complain about the missing `100.50.10.10 via 10.0.0.1 VLAN 2`.

I do not mind the interface name or the metric, only that address `10.50.10.10` is reached via `VLAN2` on one server, and not on the other.

I'd really appreciate any ideas and directions in solving this.

Thank you!

Comment: Cut out the lines you are not interested in (`grep`, `head`, `tail`), `sort` the remaining lines, compare with `diff`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not interested in the complete line. So, filter-out the part that you are interested in. As a quick and dirty solution for what you describe,

```
sed -n 's/ via [0-9\.]* /;/p'
```

would provide the fields that you are interested in.

However, it is better to have a reference of what the routing table should look like, and compare the the hosts' routing tables with that. It is possible, that a required route is missing on all the hosts, and then, you will get a false negative.